# How to change kendo mvc grid PageSize according to screen size?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to know, Do you have any solution for dynamic change PageSize?

If i expand my question, I want to show my grid in 10 element default but when i want to show it in big screen i want to show in 20 or 30 element?

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases, an initial set of `pageSize` by window height and on window resize set of `pageSize`.

On page load, fetch window size and set pageSize according to height:

```
var pageSize = 10;
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

console.log(windowHeight)

switch(true) {
  case windowHeight < 500:
    pageSize = 5;
    break;
  case windowHeight < 600:
    pageSize = 10;
    break;
  case windowHeight < 700:
    pageSize = 15;
    break;
} 

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "productName" },
      { field: "category" }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Water", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Juice", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Decaffeinated Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Iced Tea", category: "Beverages" },
        { productName: "Ham", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Bread", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Eggs", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Bacon", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Chips", category: "Food" },
        { productName: "Fish", category: "Food" }
      ],
      pageSize: pageSize
    },
    pageable: {
      pageSizes: true
    }
  });
```

If you are manually resizing window then track resize event and change grids page size:

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    console.log(windowHeight)

    switch(windowHeight) {
      case 440:
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.pageSize(5);
        grid.refresh();
        break;
      case 590:
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.pageSize(10);
        grid.refresh();
        break;
      case 700:
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.pageSize(15);
        grid.refresh();
        break;
      }
  });
```

Example: [Page size by height](https://dojo.telerik.com/uFEBEKUd)

**NOTE:** I'm not user of C# or asp.net or kendo for asp so I'm not completely sure if this will work in your case. Also, this is a robust example, you will need to adapt it for your cases